# Google sheet onChange trigger for single row change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, onchange, eventtrigger, custom-function

I want to run copy function with row 1 change in Sheet1 By onChange trigger
but i can not do it, please let me know is there any way

```
function copy()
{
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var lr=ss.getLastRow();
      ss.getRange("A1:CZ1").copyTo(ss.getRange(lr+1,1,1,104),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that onChange is an installable trigger so you have to create it.

Comment: @BK mandal, the onEdit(e) simple trigger is actually already sufficient for running scripts based on changes on the sheet. However, in the case of your script, I think it is better for your script to be placed in a custom "submit" button so that it will not copy the row every time a change is done in any of the cell in the row to be copied. Is my assumption of your requirement correct?

Answer (score 0):

#### Try it like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.rowStart != 1 || e.range.getSheet().getName() != "Sheet1") return;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lr=ss.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange("A1:CZ1").copyTo(ss.getRange(lr+1,1),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Comment: Row 1 only change by live data update

Comment: Yip that's what it does.  It fires on user edits

Answer (score 0):

### Try:

```
function onChange(e) {

  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === `Sheet1`) {

    if (e.source.getActiveRange().getRow() === 1) copy()

  }

}
```

Comment: Row 1 became change by live data , so in this aspect can i use  getActive Range()

Comment: Add this function to your code. Install this function by: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually . Select the function "onChange" and set the "Select event type" to "On change".